# Which star has the lowest absolute magnitude?

Tags: star, absolute-magnitude

I have seen many lists of stars with the most luminosity, mass, and temperature, but I have never seen one that is about absolute magnitude. So I'm wondering, which star has the lowest absolute magnitude (in other words, which star is the brightest when a viewer is 10 pc away)?

Comment: In which photometric band? Or are you just asking what is the most luminous star (known)?

Comment: I *assume* you're asking about brightness in the visible portion of the spectrum, i.e., ignoring ultraviolet, but you should clarify that in your question. I also assume you've seen this list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_luminous_stars

Comment: For several decades S Doradus in the Large Magellanic Cloud was listed as the most luminous known star, and it was actually mentioned as the most luminous star in some classic works of science fiction set centuries or millennia in the future.  But "science marches on" https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/main/sciencemarcheson  and now "the great and glorious S Doradus" is only number 78 on this list https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_luminous_stars if I counted correctly.

Comment: I thought R136a was it, because it has the highest luminosity?

Comment: "lists of stars with the most luminosity"  The star with the most luminosity is the one with lowest absolute magnitude.

Comment: Going to close this question as it obviously lacked prior research.

Answer (score 0):

The star with the lowest absoulete magnitute is called [Godzilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla_(star)) with an absoulete magnitude under -14. I'm talking about the star, not the Japanese monster, the TV shows, the movies, or the games by that name. Some other records it holds:

1. It is also the most luminous star known.
2. It's also the farthest star known to be at 1 million Solar
   Luminousities or greater.
3. Finally, it has the largest apparent visual magnitude as well.

Comment: I don't think your point #2 is true, actually. The star called [Earendel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHL0137-LS) is likely $>10^6\,L_\odot$ (which is an arbitrary threshold), maybe even $10^7\,L_\odot$, and is 1.5× farther away than "Godzilla". Your point #3 is definitely not true. Point #1 is of course true if indeed it has the lowest absolute magnitude.