# Heaviest star in universe

Tags: star, universe

Using the estimated age of the universe, can we calculate the heaviest star in the universe using normal fusion reaction rate of our sun? Assuming the star did not die.

Comment: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/47550/what-if-hypothetically-ton-618-could-have-been-a-star/47555#47555

Comment: I assume by "heaviest" you mean "most massive"? Heavy implies a gravitational force from a second object acting on the mass of the star.

Comment: Related: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/38499/31410